# I have freespace inside a partition that I can't reassign

Tags: linux, partition, disk

'm a disaster when it comes to Linux, despite trying my best lol.

I hope someone could help me with this one...

As you can see from this pic

enter image description here

I have 90GB of free space inside my main partition which I would like to allocate to partition[[image: partition I want to allocate space to1] n°7 (the second to last on the right).

The issue is that for some reason as you can see from the image, the device is /dev/sda,
[image]

from what I unserstand after doing some reaserch, the root partition. But inside partition n°1, device dev/sda1
[image]

Moreover, when I try to reallocate space via the disk "application" in linux, I get...
[image]

Like I said, I might have just talked pure nonsense, but honestly I don't know how else to put this.

Of course if you need any extra information just let me know, and I will replay ASAP. os is linux mint 19.3 BTW

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

My Spanish(?) isn't great but my best guess is that you have reached the limit of primary partitions on your disk, see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/PartitioningBasics#:%7E:text=You%20can%20only%20create%20four,you%20might%20want%20to%20create.)

**First backup any important data, this procedure could be dangerous.**

There are a few ways to solve this, I would suggest doing this:

Boot a live CD/USB and extend the NTFS partition with the additional space to the left.

Then once that is done and you confirmed your Windows partition is still working;

Shrink the NTFS partition and add the new free space to the existing EXT4 partition (#7).

This will take a while but it is straightforward and despite my earlier remark quite safe(I've done such things many times without problems).

Comment: It's italian, close enough ahahahah.  Jokes aside, thank you very much! I will try that :)

Comment: This is hardly an answer. First of all, there's no primary partition on the drive but only on extended. More importantly, rather than extend to the left (which isn't quite a thing, at least not really an "atomic" action), the existing (logical) partition(s) needs to be *moved* to the left. And there's no concrete pointer on what can do that. (Well, gparted)

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have mentioned that gparted is the tool for the job. The answer was kept very plain on purpose since the user obviously has very little experience.